# Different answers: two simple identical integer calculations?

Tags: c++, integer

Below there are two scenarios where the operations are seemingly identical but produce results different by 1. I don't think I need to explain the programming, it's very simple.

The variable declarations are first, scenario 1 is 1) and 2 = 2), and the results obtained are listed last in each scenario.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
int intWorkingNumber = 176555;

int intHundreds = 1;

int intPower = 1;
```

1)

```
int intDeductionValue = (intHundreds * 100 * pow(1000, intPower));

intWorkingNumber -= intDeductionValue;  

intWorkingNumber = 76555
```

2)

```
intWorkingNumber -= (intHundreds * 100 * pow(1000, intPower))

intWorkingNumber = 76554
```

Comment: 'double pow( double base, double exp );' - FP  not integer arithmetic, so results like yours are just expected.

Comment: Thanks to J Steen for editing my question- indentation formatting for code is noted.

Comment: @Mark Note the question mark at the end- the sentence was implied to mean "Are these two simple identical integer calculations?". Nonetheless, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The difference between the two code samples is when you cast to int.

The first version is similar to this code, where you cast to integer *before* you subtract:

```
intWorkingNumber = 176555 - (int)(1 * 100 * pow(1000, 1));
```

The second version is similar to this, where you cast to integer *after* you subtract:

```
intWorkingNumber = (int)(176555 - (1 * 100 * pow(1000, 1)));
```

The function `pow` returns a floating point number. If the result of `1 * 100 * pow(1000, 1)` is not *exactly* equal to `100000.0000` (and with floating point operations, you should not normally rely on exact results) these two are not equivalent.

Consider this simpler example:

```
x = 10 - (int)0.001;   // x = 10 - 0;     => x = 10
y = (int)(10 - 0.001); // y = (int)9.999; => y = 9
```

Comment: Must mention that `pow` returns a float for this to make sense.

Comment: @DeadMG: Mentioned. Thanks for the comment.